# VS2008 Update Web Reference creates naming conflicts in Reference.cs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asmx, web-reference

I have a Web service which, when updated on one computer with VS2008 works perfectly fine, but on another computer does not. The critical difference is the contents of the auto-generated Reference.cs.

In the correctly functioning environment, the methods have fully qualified class names, refering to classes in a class library. However, in the problem environment, the class names are unqualified and partial classes are declared near the end of the file. E.g.

```
public string MyMethod(MyClass pr_Class)
...
public partial class MyClass {
}
```

versus

```
public string MyMethod(Class.Library.Namespace.MyClass pr_Class)
```

This causes errors such as:

`'<ClassType>' is an ambiguous reference between <ClassLibraryNamespace>.ClassType and <WebReferenceNamespace>.ClassType`

The code is under source control. Checking out to the working environment works straight away, checking out to the problem environment will only work if the reference.cs is manually edited to be like the working environments. Transferring the project manually from problem environment to the working one only requires an "Update Web Reference" to be performed to allow compilation. Both Reference.cs files claim to be auto-generated by the same tool version. The settings from the good environment have been exported to the other. No success so far...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Matt

Comment: It sounds like the two environments have different versions of VS.NET. Maybe one has 2008 and the other has 2008 SP1?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately they are the same version with SP1. One difference, however, is that the working environment also has an existing VS2005 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have the answer. The working environment has a long forgotten extension library for importing web references. [Customizing generated Web Service proxies](https://web.archive.org/web/20100111055458/http://www.microsoft.com/belux/msdn/nl/community/columns/jdruyts/wsproxy.mspx) explains the procedure. I'm new to the project and so had no idea about this!

Comment: @kttii, I'd question the need for SOAP proxies in 2018... but still, I can't find where MS has moved this to. Changed to a WayBackMachine link.

Comment: Thank you sir, that helps.  I cannot recall how I found this answer but the text was ambiguous enough that I couldn't decipher it enough to find an alternate.